# Apply boosting factor for date values in the past and in the future

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

All my documents have date field and these dates can be in the past and in the future. What I need is to boost documents that correspond to dates in the range (now - 2 weeks, now + 2 weeks).
But the documentation says:

> In the current service release, one end of the range will be fixed to the current time. The other end is a time in the past based on the **boostingDuration**. To boost a range of times in the future, use a negative **boostingDuration**.

So I cannot boost documents in the past and in the future by one scoring profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a view with the calculated column:
 case
  when EntryDate < getdate() then EntryDate
  else dateadd(minute, -datediff(minute, getdate(), EntryDate), getdate())
  end as VenueEventStartDateDiffAbs

This expression return the same output for (now - x days) and (now + x days). Applying boostDuration for this column allows to get maximum score for current date.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to add a field to your document containing the date-2 weeks, and then apply positive boost from there. It introduces a bit of redundancy but it would unblock the situation.

Comment: Hmm, in this case (now - 2 weeks) will have the maximum score. It's more useful to have maximum score for current date.